# How app can restore data after clearing by user?

Tags: android

I develop an Android application which dynamically creates some files and stores them to /data/data/{my-app}/files directory. If user cleared app data using Android Settings, all that files will be deleted. How can I persist them to be restored when user launch my app again?

I've noticed that TikTok app can store files located in it's private directory (/data/data/com.zhiliaoapp.musically/) and restore them after clearing app data. How can app do it?

I've tested such behavour on rooted Android 11 device:

1. cp /storage/emulated/0/Download/foo.txt /data/data/com.zhiliaoapp.musically/files/foo.txt
2. Clear TikTok data
3. Launch TikTok again
4. foo.txt will appear in /data/data/com.zhiliaoapp.musically/files/foo.txt

Phone has no google account and backup is disabled. Google play is disabled also.
I thought that TikTok downloads data from server. So I changed all possible identifiers (android id, advertising id, imei, etc) after clearing data and disabled Internet access, but foo.txt still restores. So it definitely persists locally.

How can I implement same behaviour in my app?

Comment: Tik Tok just creates that file if it does not exist.

Comment: It is my own file. I create it manually and copy to TikTok private directory. Than clear TikTok data by Android GUI. And when I launch TikTok again I can see that file. How TikTok knows something about that file and it's contents?

Comment: it is an interesting observation. maybe TikTok is implementing https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupAgent in some sophisticated way. or just plain on implementing their own backup mechanism since they already have storage permission.

Comment: Switch off the phone after clearing the data first.

Comment: I've tried to reboot after clearing data. Same result.

Comment: @Joe They don't have storage permission. At least at this step. TikTok asks for storage access later, when user tries to upload a video.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.